# cacti does not show graphs

Tags: linux, cacti, graphical-user-interface

reinstall an operating system and some graphs do not work for me and others do, especially one of the ones I need is this one and it does not show data
I show you here the debug in case anyone sees an error

```
 Comando RRDtool:
/usr/bin/rrdtool graph - \
--imgformat=PNG \
--start='-86400' \
--end='-60' \
--pango-markup  \
--title='TITAN_5 - Memory Usage' \
--vertical-label='bytes' \
--slope-mode \
--base=1000 \
--height=200 \
--width=700 \
--tabwidth '40' \
--rigid \
--alt-autoscale-max \
--lower-limit='0' \
COMMENT:"From 2022-01-31 15\:52\:22 To 2022-02-01 15\:51\:22\c" \
COMMENT:"  \n" \
--color BACK#F3F3F3 \
--color CANVAS#FDFDFD \
--color SHADEA#CBCBCB \
--color SHADEB#999999 \
--color FONT#000000 \
--color AXIS#2C4D43 \
--color ARROW#2C4D43 \
--color FRAME#2C4D43 \
--border 1 --font TITLE:11:'Arial' \
--font AXIS:8:'Arial' \
--font LEGEND:8:'Courier' \
--font UNIT:8:'Arial' \
--font WATERMARK:6:'Arial' \
--slope-mode \
--watermark 'Generated by Zapi' \
DEF:a='/var/www/html/cacti-1.2.16/rra/titan_5_mem_total_4916.rrd':'mem_total':AVERAGE \
DEF:b='/var/www/html/cacti-1.2.16/rra/titan_5_mem_buffers_4913.rrd':'mem_buffers':AVERAGE \
DEF:c='/var/www/html/cacti-1.2.16/rra/titan_5_mem_cache_4914.rrd':'mem_cache':AVERAGE \
DEF:d='/var/www/html/cacti-1.2.16/rra/titan_5_mem_free_4915.rrd':'mem_free':AVERAGE \
DEF:e='/var/www/html/cacti-1.2.16/rra/titan_5_mem_total_4916.rrd':'mem_total':MAX \
DEF:f='/var/www/html/cacti-1.2.16/rra/titan_5_mem_buffers_4913.rrd':'mem_buffers':MAX \
DEF:g='/var/www/html/cacti-1.2.16/rra/titan_5_mem_cache_4914.rrd':'mem_cache':MAX \
DEF:h='/var/www/html/cacti-1.2.16/rra/titan_5_mem_free_4915.rrd':'mem_free':MAX \
CDEF:cdefa='a,1024,*' \
CDEF:cdefe='b,1024,*' \
CDEF:cdefi='c,1024,*' \
CDEF:cdefbc='d,1024,*' \
CDEF:cdefbg='e,1024,*' \
CDEF:cdefbh='f,1024,*' \
CDEF:cdefbi='g,1024,*' \
CDEF:cdefbj='h,1024,*' \
AREA:cdefa#15317E7F:'Memory Total  '  \
GPRINT:cdefa:LAST:'Current\:%8.2lf %s'  \
GPRINT:cdefa:AVERAGE:'Average\:%8.2lf %s'  \
GPRINT:a:MAX:'Maximum\:%8.2lf %s\n'  \
AREA:cdefe#FF57007F:'Memory Buffers'  \
GPRINT:cdefe:LAST:'Current\:%8.2lf %s'  \
GPRINT:cdefe:AVERAGE:'Average\:%8.2lf %s'  \
GPRINT:cdefe:MAX:'Maximum\:%8.2lf %s\n'  \
AREA:cdefi#FFC73B7F:'Cache Memory  ':STACK \
GPRINT:cdefi:LAST:'Current\:%8.2lf %s'  \
GPRINT:cdefi:AVERAGE:'Average\:%8.2lf %s'  \
GPRINT:cdefi:MAX:'Maximum\:%8.2lf %s\n'  \
AREA:cdefbc#8F005C7F:'Memory Free   ':STACK \
GPRINT:cdefbc:LAST:'Current\:%8.2lf %s'  \
GPRINT:cdefbc:AVERAGE:'Average\:%8.2lf %s'  \
GPRINT:cdefbc:MAX:'Maximum\:%8.2lf %s\n'  \
LINE1:cdefbg#151B8DFF:  \
LINE1:cdefbh#FF5700FF:  \
LINE1.00:cdefbi#FFC73BFF::STACK \
LINE1.00:cdefbj#8F005CFF::STACK
RRDtool Command lengths = 2373 charaters.
RRDtool dice:
OK
```

Comment: any idea where to go? I don't know if it's a matter of lis mib or rrd....

Comment: any idea where to go? I don't know if it's a matter of lis mib or rrd...